# WriteDec stops working after 5 calls, in a loop storing to an array?

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

for a class project we're asked to create a Fibonacci sequence program. I am using Visual Studio 2017 to run my program (32 bit). All goes well when I run the below program until I try to print to console the 6th number in the sequence, 5, (0,1,1,2,3,5). Nothing past the 5th number is being outputted to the console. I am using the WriteDec procedure from Irvine32 Library to accomplish to [write decimals](http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/writedec.htm) to the console.

I am bamboozled because `eax` register holds the right values when I step through in debugger mode, but WriteDec won't print it out. The address of the array I use to store Fibonacci numbers has these values when computing the 8th term of the sequence :
 `0x00406000  00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 08 00 00 00 0d 00 00 00`

The output looks like:

`0
1
123`

```
  ;Fibionacci Sequence

; This program outputs a fibonacci sequence and sum

Include Irvine32.inc

.data
array DWORD 0,1

.code

main proc
    mov ecx, 6 ; would be the 8th term in the sequence
    mov esi, 4
    mov eax, 0
    call WriteDec
    call crlf
    mov eax, 1
    call WriteDec
    call crlf
    L1: 
        mov edx, array[esi]
        mov edi, array[esi-4]
        add edx,edi
        mov array[esi+4],edx
        mov eax, edx
        call WriteDec ; Writes an unsigned 32-bit decimal number to standard output in decimal format with no leading zeros.
        add esi,4
    loop L1
    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Does it help if you add `call crlf` inside the loop, like you have outside the loop?  The actual output you show doesn't match your program, because you don't show any newlines.  (I haven't used Irvine32, only seen SO questions about it.  I wasn't aware it worked at all in a 64-bit program.  But anyway, it probably isn't doing line-buffered output the way printf would.)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: if your program is 64-bit as you say, why are you overriding the address-size to 32-bit by using `array[esi]` instead of `array[rsi]`?  Also, you could save an instruction by producing the new Fibonacci number in EAX in the first place, because you're reloading both Fib(n-2) and Fib(n-1) from memory every time instead of reusing the value in EDX.  (Of course it would be better to do something like `add edx, array[rsi-4]` / `mov array[rsi+4], edx` / `mov eax,edx`.  IIRC, Irvine32 functions preserve all registers except maybe EAX as the return value, so EDX survives.)

Comment: sorry i made a mistake. i am running this program on 32 bit system. i will edit my post to show the correct output. call crlf inside loop doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: Your Windows is 32-bit?  That's unfortunate.  The normal way to run 32-bit programs these days is under a 64-bit OS.

Comment: When you write past the end of the two dwords you reserved for your `array DWORD 0,1`, you're probably overwriting some data that `WriteDec` uses.

Comment: how could i test if writedec overwrites data? I looked it up and its call arguments are from eax register, which doesn't seem to be related to the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write past the end of the two dwords you reserved for your `array DWORD 0,1`, you're probably overwriting some data that WriteDec uses.

> how could i test if writedec overwrites data?

You have it backwards.  *Your code* is writing outside your array.  **The linker probably puts it right before some data that `WriteDec` needs to read**, e.g. maybe a file handle for the console or something.  So after you step on WriteDec's constants, future calls to it stop printing anything.

Your debugger output confirms that `WriteDec` didn't overwrite the Fibonacci sequence values you stored, so we can conclude that `WriteDec` isn't *writing* to that memory, just reading it.

And also that it's not a pointer, or it would crashed when overwrote it with small integers.

---

Try something like

```
array DWORD 0,1
  DWORD 10 DUP(?)       ;  or DUP(0)  because that's what you'll really get
```

to make a larger array with explicit initializers for the first 2 values, then more space in the same section.

Comment: holy moly you're right! I guess it makes sense to always allocate space for the array. Is there no such thing as dynamic arrays in assembly like Java'a arraylist?

Comment: @st4rgut: Sure, making them on the stack with `push` works well.  But stuff like C++ `std::vector<int>` has to check for space, and reallocate + copy all the elements if needed, every time you grow it.  If you want to write code for that(!), go nuts.  But that only works with dynamic storage, not static like you're using.  `array DWORD 0,1 ` is exactly like C `static int array[] = {0,1};`.  Adding the extra line after makes it like `static int array[12] = {0, 1}`.  Something like `static std::vector<int> array(12) = {1,2};` would keep its pointers in static storage, but call `new` for memory.

Comment: @st4rgut on HW level there's no dynamic memory. The chips inserted into the board have N bits in total, and that's it. What looks as "dynamic" memory in high level languages is dynamic allocation of the finite physical memory amount to the different processes/threads, with modern OS even being capable to allocate non-existent memory to the the process, filing up its needs by swapping already occupied physical memory content to disk, then reassigning that physical memory to other process (requesting memory), and making it "stored on disk" for the previous one, i.e. imaginary. = not trivial.